# How can show image on submit button?

Tags: html, css, button, submit, background-image

I have a submit button and I want to show an image(a.jpg) on that button and won't show the value of submit button. Is it possible in case of a 'submit' type button ? (not "type='image'")

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

-Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `<button type="submit">` instead?

Comment: Why not use `type="image"` and submit the form on the click event for it?

Comment: isn't that possible in case of 'submit' type button ?

Comment: button type="submit" would give you more freedom, as long as you don't need a value of the submit in backend (some older browsers do not support a value of a button tag.

Comment: I tried "<button type="submit" value="submit" style="background:a.jpg;" />" but not working on mozilla firefox latest version

Comment: Should work with:  style="background-image:url(a.jpg)";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS to style the button approprately

```
​<input id="it" type="submit" value="Submit">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

```
​#it{
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
    font-size:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9XuW/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="submit" name="foo" value="bar">
    <img src="image.png" alt="submit">
</button>
```

Comment: this option has cross browser issue for example in ipad